# PrestaShop Addons size limited to 50Mb with a hardcoded value?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7, prestashop-modules

I was trying to upload a custom module to prestashop 1.7, and get this error:

> File is too big (52.59MiB). Max filesize: 50MiB.

I've checked with phpinfo that it's not caused by my php settings:

> memory_limit  512M
>
> post_max_size 150M
>
> upload_max_filesize   100M

Searching on the web, I find that this value seems to be hardcoded on the file:

> adminblahblahblah/themes/default/js/bundle/module/module.js

One of its lines says:

> maxFilesize: 50, // can't be greater than 50Mb because it's an addons
> limitation

But editing that value, donesn't seem to do nothing.

It's really hardcoded this value and is an addons limitation? or can be changed and how?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: In PrestaShop v.1.7.8.7 is NOT hardcoded. Sure! The maxFilesize you have found is a limitation just for Dropzone. Also, in v.1.7.8.7 I don't find the literal "Max filesize" (in php nor tpl files). The error you get is shown by PrestaShop? Wich version?

Comment: I'm in PrestaShop 1.7.8.5. You can reproduce it by: Back Office -> Module manager -> Upload a module -> Select or drop a file of more than 50M -> Error message (cliking on "What happened?") -> File is too big (52.59MiB). Max filesize: 50MiB. Seem's that the code may be on the default theme: adminblahblahblah/themes/default/js/bundle/module/module.js there's a line that says: maxFilesize: 50, // can't be greater than 50Mb because it's an addons limitation

Comment: Yes, that code is in 1.7.8.7 too, but it's a limitation just for Dropzone, nothing to do with uploading a module. I will try to upload a file bigger that 50M and see what happens. I will tell you.

Comment: thanks! Yes, maybe the limitation is from dropzone js library. But it's also strange because it seems that dropzone library default file size limit is 256MB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes, it's hardcoded!

It's hardcoded in a javascript file, quite similar to the one you found.

### This is the file here the limitation is:

`[admindir]/themes/new-theme/public/module.bundle.js`

Just search for "maxFilesize", and you will find:
`maxFilesize:50` (no space between `:` and `50`).

That's the limitation that acts when you try to upload a module.
It's javascript, so the check is made before really uploading the file.

Changing that value in that file will do the job.

There are a few more files where is declared a file upload limitation, but the one mentioned is the *guilty* when uploading modules.

**Tested in PrestaShop v.1.7.8.7**

Comment: Thanks! Do you think this can be considered a bug? Is it worth opening a ticket?

Comment: @psaudela Ummm, I think this can't be considered a bug. There is a good reason to check filesize before uploading it, and 50M for a compressed module is a lot, also they say is the limitation in PrestaShop Addons. And you have the alternative to upload the module by FTP. However, it would be nice if that value was configurable in some way, and of course publishing a module to Addons is not a must. Just for curiosity, why does your module weigh so much?

Comment: I have three javascript libraries: flexslider, ytplayer and fawesome. But, now that you mention it... at fawesome I have all the symbols, not the five or six that I'm currently using, and that's 24M total. So with little effort I can reduce weight almost at half. :-)
Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

it seems to do many debugs to show the solution
so if you have access to your ftp server just upload the module to /modules folder then install it from the bo

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm doing, but then every time i have to add it also manually to the database. Also, i have curiosity to know if this value it's really hard coded.